# Can the IV be reused if the key is changed?

Tags: aes, symmetric, initialization-vector

I am using AES-GCM-256 to encrypt data in a database, and am using a single key that I salt with a unique random value for each user to encrypt their information. I am using the same IV for all of this.

Is this secure so long as I change the key each time?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this secure so long as I change the key each time?

Yes, using the same IV with different keys is perfectly safe.

However, if you encrypt some data for a user, and then the user updates his data, will you encrypt that new data with the same key?  If so, well, you've just used the same (key, iv) pair for two separate sets of data

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will make sure to change the key each time.